# finding the difference in years for two common values in a column

Tags: pandas, group-by

I'm using pandas and I'm trying to find the difference in years when my data is grouped by labels and then by teams.  i've tried to use a groupby for the problem that I'm dealing with but I can't quite get my desired result.  here is the head(8) of my df

```
Team            Year    labels
Hawks           2001      b
Hawks           2004      b
Nets            1987      b
Nets            1988      a
Nets            2004      b
Nets            2001      a
Nets            2000      c
Hawks           2003      a
```

so, what confuses me is there are basically two groups that I want - labels and team.  i then need to find the difference between the years which would be sorted and the result would be in the difference column.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Team            Year    labels  difference
Hawks           2001      b       NAN
Hawks           2004      b        1
Nets            1987      b       NAN
Nets            1988      a       NAN
Nets            2004      b       17
Nets            2001      a       13
Nets            2000      c       NAN
Hawks           2003      b        2
```

Comment: The last row in the data has a label of 'a'  but the expect output has a label of 'b'. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if `label` for the last row is supposed to be 'a' or 'b'. From your data snippet:

```
Hawks           2003      a
```

From you expected output:

```
Hawks           2003      b        2
```

I'll assume `label` is supposed to be 'b' so I can match your expected output:

You want do a groupby on ['Team', 'Labels'] which you can use to compute the year difference. But first sort your data by ['Team','labels','Year'] so your year difference calcs are correct:

```
In [8]: df.sort(['Team','labels','Year'],inplace=True)
In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
    Team  Year labels
0  Hawks  2001      b
7  Hawks  2003      b
1  Hawks  2004      b
3   Nets  1988      a
5   Nets  2001      a
2   Nets  1987      b
4   Nets  2004      b
6   Nets  2000      c
```

Now, do a groupby on ['Team','labels'] and compute the difference between years for each row in the group:

```
In [10]: df['difference'] = df.groupby(['Team','labels'])['Year'].diff(1)
In [11]: df
    Team  Year labels  difference
0  Hawks  2001      b         NaN
7  Hawks  2003      b           2
1  Hawks  2004      b           1
3   Nets  1988      a         NaN
5   Nets  2001      a          13
2   Nets  1987      b         NaN
4   Nets  2004      b          17
6   Nets  2000      c         NaN
```

And if for some reason you want to go back to the original order of the dataframe you can do the following:

```
In [12]: df.sort_index()
Out[12]: 
    Team  Year labels  difference
0  Hawks  2001      b         NaN
1  Hawks  2004      b           1
2   Nets  1987      b         NaN
3   Nets  1988      a         NaN
4   Nets  2004      b          17
5   Nets  2001      a          13
6   Nets  2000      c         NaN
7  Hawks  2003      b           2
```

Comment: thanks so much - i didn't realize you could groupby with two columns - that was my problem.  the one question i have is why is there a 1 in diff(1) ?

Comment: You're right; you could just do `diff()` since the default is `periods = 1`. I was just being explicit.

Comment: oh thanks!  i actually had no idea about that.  really helpful though!